# what is the relationship between 2 classes?

Tags: java, oop

If i have Class A and Class B what is the relation-ship between them if nothing else is stated (no HAS-A) relation-ship stated, is it Association?

```
class A{}
class B{}
```

Comment: on the presented information. there is no relationship at all

Comment: There is no relationship here, objects can be parent-child, have association (aggregation and composition) relationship, or have dependency relationship. According to your sample there is none.

Comment: Another way to look at things: if there _were_ a relationship among them worthy of a name, or at least worthy of a particular kind of arrow in UML, say, then (nearly) every class would be related to every other and it would make our diagrams very messy. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no relation between those classes.

The only relationship that I can see is that they both implicitly inherit from `Object`.

Answer (score 5):

They are the child classes of the parent class called `java.lang.Object` , other than that , there is no visible relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you supplied. No, there is no relationship. In java, both inherit from the java.lang.Object. But from OO perspective, there is no relationship.

Class can be related in the following ways:

Aggregation - This is a has-a relationship where Class A has at least 1 field whose type is of classB
Inheritance - This is an is-a relationship where a class B is a specialization of another class A. In this kind of relationship, the classB inherits all the behaviours of the class A.